# jQuery querySelectorAll not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a simple **filter as you type** for my nav bar, I've got the following but doesn't appear to be working correctly:

```
$("input[id='gameSearch']").on('keydown', function(e) {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = $(this);
          filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
          div = $('#gamesDropdown');
          a = div.querySelectorAll("li a");
          for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              if (a[i].html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  a[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                  a[i].style.display = "none";
              }
          }
      });
```

I've got my HTML layout as such:

```
<ul id="gamesDropdown">
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="gameSearch" placeholder="Search...">
    <li>
    <li>
        <a href="#blah">Blah blah</a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <a href="#blah">Blah blah</a>
    <li>
    <li>
        <a href="#blah">Blah blah</a>
    <li>
</ul>
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: div.querySelectorAll is not a function
```

Has this been deprecated or am I just using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll` is for vanilla js, you can either do:

```
a = div.get().querySelectorAll("li a");
```

and then stick to vanilla js, or you can do

```
a = div.find("li a");
```

and then `a` will be a `jQuery` object so you can do `.html()` like you do later in your code, but it will need to be like:

```
a = div.find("li a");
a.each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
       $(this).css('display', '');
    } else {
       $(this).css('display', 'none');
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) method to get a reference to the DOM element:

```
$("input[id='gameSearch']").on('keydown', function(e) {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = $(this);
          filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
          div = $('#gamesDropdown');
          a = div.get(0).querySelectorAll("li a");
          for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              if ($(a[i]).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  a[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                  a[i].style.display = "none";
              }
          }
      });
```